# Nested uiOutput within RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In a nutshell, I *believe* I need to nest uiOutputs together and cannot figure a great way to do so.

The app is large but for this part, I would like to create a survey that renders sub-surveys (new panels) based on a slider input (I've accomplished that much). These panels will all be standard and so they can be created with a loop.

However, answers within these panels should generate more UI within the panel from which they were generated and therein lies the problem... the nesting of uiOutputs. I've tried to provide the shortest example possible below, with comments - and note that the second uiOutput call works if I specify a panel for which it should work ("oh_lawd_1" in this case).

Please let me know what you think! Have been looking at this in my spare time for at least 4 days. (also I realize that this is not an ideal use of shiny).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage( #UI

  column(6, offset = 3,
    sliderInput(inputId = "my_slider",     # slider to choose number of panels
                label = "Choose Panels to be Displayed",
                min = 0, max = 5, value = 1),
    uiOutput(outputId = "update_panels")   # ui output to create panels

  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { #Server

  output$update_panels <- renderUI({     # rendering all the panels called for by user

    panels <- input$my_slider

    if(panels == 0){
      return("No panels being displayed")# returning 0 if none selected
    } else {
      our_ui <- list()                   # creating a list to store a standard panel
      for(i in 1:panels){
        button_id <- paste("button_id", i, sep = "_") # a unique id for each panel's radiobuttons
        oh_lawd   <- paste("oh_lawd", i, sep = "_")         # a unique id for each panel's uiOutput
        update    <- wellPanel(paste("Well Panel #", i),    # "update" is what each panel should START OFF looking like
                            radioButtons(inputId = button_id, 
                                         label = "Choose a pill", 
                                         choices = c("Red Pill", "Blue Pill")),
                            uiOutput(oh_lawd))     # this part is the issue - I would like to update individual panels with a 
                                                   # radio button selection specific to a choice in each panel... a nested uiOutput
        our_ui <- list(our_ui, update)
      }}
    our_ui})


  output$oh_lawd_1 <- renderUI({     # this works for the first... but I need to somehow create one of these for each based on
                                   # number of panels and the choice in each panel
    if(input$button_id_1 == "Red Pill"){
      radioButtons("first_output", "Next Choices", choices = c("I'm a brave boi", "Knowledge schmoledge"))
    } else {
      radioButtons("first_output", "Next Choices", choices = c("Gimme dat ignorance", "Mhmm yea") )
    }
  })             

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you want? I'm not sure.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage( #UI

  column(6, offset = 3,
         sliderInput(inputId = "my_slider",     # slider to choose number of panels
                     label = "Choose Panels to be Displayed",
                     min = 0, max = 5, value = 1),
         uiOutput(outputId = "update_panels")   # ui output to create panels

  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { #Server

  output$update_panels <- renderUI({     # rendering all the panels called for by user

    panels <- input$my_slider

    if(panels == 0){
      return("No panels being displayed")# returning 0 if none selected
    } else {
      our_ui <- list()                   # creating a list to store a standard panel
      for(i in 1:panels){
        button_id <- paste("button_id", i, sep = "_") # a unique id for each panel's radiobuttons
        oh_lawd   <- paste("oh_lawd", i, sep = "_")         # a unique id for each panel's uiOutput
        update    <- wellPanel(paste("Well Panel #", i),    # "update" is what each panel should START OFF looking like
                               radioButtons(inputId = button_id, 
                                            label = "Choose a pill", 
                                            choices = c("Red Pill", "Blue Pill")),
                               uiOutput(oh_lawd))     # this part is the issue - I would like to update individual panels with a 
        # radio button selection specific to a choice in each panel... a nested uiOutput
        our_ui <- list(our_ui, update)
      }}
    our_ui})

  observeEvent(input$my_slider, {
    lapply(seq_len(input$my_slider), function(i){
      uiID <- paste0("oh_lawd_", i)
      buttonID <- paste0("button_id_", i)
      radioID <- paste0("radio_id_", i)
      output[[uiID]] <- renderUI({
        if(input[[buttonID]] == "Red Pill"){
          choices <- c("I'm a brave boi", "Knowledge schmoledge")
        }else{
          choices <- c("Gimme dat ignorance", "Mhmm yea")
        }
        radioButtons(radioID, "Next Choices", choices = choices)
      })
    })
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Wonderful - seems like I was close but couldn't quite figure out how/where to store all the created uis after the loop. Storing it in Output[[uiID]] in this case makes perfect sense and is so obvious. Thank you for taking the time to answer it! (also having it be produced as a dependency of the slider is something I had not thought about)